# Do infants need to apply for a separate US visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I have a J1 visa and I'm staying in the USA. I am planning to bring my wife and my son (5 months old). Do they have to apply for separate visas, or can my wife include our son's details in her form?

How about fees?

Comment: afaik every person needs their own visa. I had to do a visa for my 11-month-old. She needed her own DS160 as well. It literally took me 3 hours to fill out all the DS160 forms online.